# CakePHP cascading foreign keys to get a user list

Tags: cakephp, foreign-keys, cakephp-model

I have a table for users, a table for cities and a table for states. Each `user` has a `city`, identified by `city_id` in its columns, and each `city` is related to a `state` by `state_id` key.

I want to get a list of users in each state, but I don't know how to access the `user` list using the `city` and the `state`.

All of them have, of course, their models, views and controllers (generated by bake). I didn't make any changes after bake generated them, except for users, whose password is salted and hashed before inclusion.

CakePHP is the latest (2.2.4), I'm using an AMP stack installed by myself and correctly configured.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed.  It's a common problem to not understand how to get related data via associations, and the question made enough sense to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).  Your code should then look something like this:

```
$this->State->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'City' => array(
            'User'
        )
    )
));
```

Then, your data will come back something like this (off top of my head):

```
>State
  >0
    id
    name
    >City
      >0
        id
        name
          >User
            >0
              id
              name
              email
            >1
              id
              name
              email
       >1
         id
         ...etc
```

Comment: I couldn't understand which one of them should be a containable. I found the documentation to be somewhat confusing, lol.

Will update if any progress is made.

Comment: Just set `public $actsAs = array('Containable');` in your AppModel and have it available for all of them.